# UILabel is not getting updated in ViewController swift3

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift3

I am parsing data from json and put them into variables then use those variables to change the value of UILabel but they're(UILabel) not getting updated, I have searched through the internet and they've said it is the result of updating UIlabel from thread other than main thread but here I have put it in viewController but still not getting updated
and here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class NewsContentViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nuTitle: UILabel!
    var namesArray = String()
    var iD = String()
    var description1 = String()
    var iDArray = [String]()


    @IBOutlet weak var tctView: UITextView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        parseJSON()



        nuTitle.text = self.namesArray
        tctView.text = self.description1

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




func parseJSON(){



    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "XXXXXX" + iD)!
    print(requestURL)
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in


        let readableJSON = JSON(data: data! , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)





            if let Name = readableJSON[0]["Title"].string as String! {
                var ID = readableJSON[0]["Id"].intValue
                var iDString = String (ID)
                self.namesArray.append(Name)

                var desc = readableJSON[0]["Description"].string as String!
                var type = readableJSON[0]["Type_Name"].string

            self.iDArray.append(iDString)

            self.description1 = desc!
            self.namesArray = Name


        } 
    }
    task.resume()


}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

The problem here is that the task inside `parseJSON()` will be executed asynchronously. And by the time that

```
nuTitle.text = self.namesArray
tctView.text = self.description1
```

that will be executed, task has not yet returned results.

Please read more about threading in iOS [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

### Solution

A proper solution on this case is for you to add a `completionBlock` which will return your data back.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    parseJSON { (description, name) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.description1 = description
            self.namesArray = name
            nuTitle.text = self.namesArray
            tctView.text = self.description1
        }
    }
}

func parseJSON(completion: @escaping (_ description: String, _ name: String) -> Void) {
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "XXXXXX" + iD)!
    print(requestURL)
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        
        
        let readableJSON = JSON(data: data! , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)

        if let Name = readableJSON[0]["Title"].string as String! {
            var ID = readableJSON[0]["Id"].intValue
            var iDString = String (ID)
            self.namesArray.append(Name)
            
            var desc = readableJSON[0]["Description"].string as String!
            var type = readableJSON[0]["Type_Name"].string
            
            self.iDArray.append(iDString)
            
            completion(desc!, Name)
        } 
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func parseJSON(){



    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "XXXXXX" + iD)!
    print(requestURL)
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in


        let readableJSON = JSON(data: data! , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)





            if let Name = readableJSON[0]["Title"].string as String! {
                var ID = readableJSON[0]["Id"].intValue
                var iDString = String (ID)
                self.namesArray.append(Name)

                var desc = readableJSON[0]["Description"].string as String!
                var type = readableJSON[0]["Type_Name"].string

            self.iDArray.append(iDString)

            self.description1 = desc!
            self.namesArray = Name
       // assign text here to label 
       nuTitle.text = self.namesArray
        tctView.text = self.description1


        }
```